# Trying to push into a struct array

Tags: arrays, struct, solidity

I am getting this error:

contracts/Simple Contracts/NFT.sol:21:18: ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('
nftArray.push(nftOne);
^

```
// Struct for storing our NFT's
struct NFT {
    string contractAddress;
    uint256 tokenID;
    string tokenStandard;
    string blockChain;
    uint256 creatorFees;
}

NFT nftOne = NFT("0xD9D24a4b8A58BCdBfDDd0d27B51F27", 345,"ERC-721", "ETHEREUM", 721);
NFT nftTwo = NFT("0xD9824a4b8A5u8CdBfDDd0d27B51F27", 346,"ERC-721", "ETHEREUM", 721);
NFT nftThree = NFT("0xD9DE9824a4b8A58BCdBfDDd0Y1F27", 347,"ERC-721", "ETHEREUM", 721);

NFT[] nftArray;
nftArray.push(nftOne);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because the solidity compiler expects variable or function identifier, but got an expression `nftArray.push(nftOne);`. Consider moving it to a constructor like this:

```
struct NFT {
    string contractAddress;
    uint256 tokenID;
    string tokenStandard;
    string blockChain;
    uint256 creatorFees;
}

NFT nftOne = NFT("0xD9D24a4b8A58BCdBfDDd0d27B51F27", 345,"ERC-721", "ETHEREUM", 721);
NFT nftTwo = NFT("0xD9824a4b8A5u8CdBfDDd0d27B51F27", 346,"ERC-721", "ETHEREUM", 721);
NFT nftThree = NFT("0xD9DE9824a4b8A58BCdBfDDd0Y1F27", 347,"ERC-721", "ETHEREUM", 721);

NFT[] nftArray;

constructor() {
    nftArray.push(nftOne);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man really appreciate it, this worked. I feel like an idiot lol.